# What is this SQL query syntax mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT b.*,
( select a.USER_NAME 
  from A.db.USER a 
  where a.USER_ID=b.Booking_Inspector
) as USER_NAME 
FROM A.dbo.Booking b 
where b.Booking_Inspector=? and b.confirm=1
```

From this sql syntax, what is "," which after "*"  mean?
and anyone can explain this query to me or tell me where I can start?

Comment: * to get all columns from table (b.* mean get all columns from table b)
, to listed columns your want to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means all the columns from table `Booking`, and to the far right (the last column per row) bring in the `user_name` column from table `user` relating on the user.user_id matching the booking.booking_inspector. Such that the Booking.confirm is 1, and Booking_inspector is filled in with a parameter passed.

So it limits the rows of output to confirm is 1 and Booking_Inspector is the parameter passed (or bound, etc) depending on the language calling it.

Select * means all columns. So all columns from the one table, and just one column from the other

Comment: Thanks for explanation, can you explain "=?" more for me? or any website i can refer to? I am using JAVA by the way.

Comment: depends on the language that calls it. It is a binding.

Comment: for instance, here it is for PHP mysqli, on [This Link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Take for instance a script that accepts a POST of booking_inspector, and an id=789 is passed in. That code of yours will be putting 789 into the place holder `?` in a prepared statement

Comment: no problem. Here it is for [Java too](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-a-prepared-statement-with-bind-variables-using-mysql.html) in a prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `(select a.USER_NAME from A.db.USER a where a.USER_ID=b.Booking_Inspector)` is the subquery which will return column `a.USER_NAME`. So this query is selecting everything from `b` (b.*) and the column `a.USER_NAME` from the subquery. So like you put comma between column names in select query, it is same.

Answer (score 1):

select all columns from b and one more column from that subquery as `USER_NAME`.

```
( select a.USER_NAME 
  from A.db.USER a 
  where a.USER_ID=b.Booking_Inspector
) as USER_NAME
```

That whole thing above as 1 column

```
SELECT b.*, [USER_NAME]
FROM A.dbo.Booking b 
where b.Booking_Inspector=? and b.confirm=1
```